# Laravel eloquent, change query if no results

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

Making a Multilingual site with fallback option to English.

I have a table "languages"

```
__________________
|language | text |
------------------
| "EN"  | "good" |
------------------
| "NL"  | "goed" |
------------------
```

My eloquent query in the controller is:

```
Languages::language('EN')->take(1)->get();
```

In the Model Languages i have a scope function:

```
public function scopeLanguage($query, $language)
{
    $query->where('language', '=', $language);
}
```

which works perfect. but i when i try to query a language that does not exist in the table.
for example:

```
Languages::language('DE')->take(1)->get();
```

it returns no results, but i want to have a fallback to "EN"

i tried thing like:

```
public function scopeLanguage($query, $language)
{
    $query->where('language', '=', $language);
    if ($query->count() > 0) {
        return $query;
    } else {
        return $query->where('language', '=', "EN");
    }
}
```

without luck, it seems it adds the new where query to the existing one. 
can i remove/alter the where query?. without breaking the chain (the actual model has multiple scope functions)

Comment: Try add `->get()` in your scope function, without execute I guess there is no result and no count as well

Comment: Doing itin the scope means, that you will ignore other `wheres` that you apply later (or scopes), so it's not the way.

Comment: If it adds `where` condition to the query you can replace it with `orWhere` and it would work fine.

Comment: @danny do you mean $query->where('language', '=', $language)->get();? and what do you mean with "without execute", the count does work btw, if i exit it in the else it works. thanks for your help

Comment: You need to get single row or really want `get` there?

Comment: @estshy thanks that worked :), please make your comment an answer so i can accept it

Comment: @JarekTkaczyk i need to get a single row

Comment: @estshy just figured out that the orWhere does break the chain

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could probably try with that:

```
public function scopeLanguage($query, $language)
{
    $q = clone $query;

    $q->where('language', '=', $language);
    if ($q->count() > 0) {
        return $query->where('language', '=', $language);
    } else {
        return $query->where('language', '=', "EN");
    }
}
```

As it is working it could be also simplified a bit

```
public function scopeLanguage($query, $language)
{
    $q = clone $query;

    $q->where('language', '=', $language);
    if ($q->count() == 0) {
        $language = 'EN';
    } 
    return $query->where('language', '=', $language);
}
```

Comment: Also results in SQL: select * from `languages` where `language` = DE and `language` = EN limit 1

Comment: You could probably clone the $query but as @JarekTkaczyk mentioned it will probably not solve the problem

Comment: @77120 Your query would return nothing each time. One `ield can't have two values at the same time.

Comment: Objects are passed by reference.

Comment: @JarekTkaczyk You are right, I've added cloning but I don't know if it will work

Comment: thanks this solution works to, with the cloning added

Comment: Hmm.. now I wonder whether cloning the original query and calling count() or my solution: doing a separated query on the (I suppose) smaller Languages table is more efficient. For sure this is more maintainable (no need to hard-wire the Languages model).

Comment: I made (a little biased) test and mine solution is TONS slower. Using a 4000rows main table for the scope and a small one (as the languages table should be) as example. Average times: Mine - 0.048372030258179 @MarcinNabiałek one: 1.0967254638672E-5

Answer (score 4):

If you don't want to break the chain you could check it on a separate query:

```
public function scopeLanguage($query, $language){
  if(!self::where('language',$language)->count()){
    $language = 'EN';
  }
  return $query->whereLanguage($language);
}
```

Comment: This solution works but I made (a little biased) test and is TONS slower than @MarcinNabiałek solution. Using a 4000rows main table for the scoping table and a small one (as the languages table should be) as example. Average times: Mine - 0.048372030258179 / MarcinNabiałek solution - 1.0967254638672E-5

Comment: Check queries, they should be the same.

Comment: Good to know, but probably one test is not enough to decide which method is quicker and which is slower

Comment: I had the time to do it again and @estshy is right I was (wrongly) thinking 'scopeLanguage' was on a different model (such as comment/post/etc). The queries executed are exactly the same. So Your solution is more maintainable, but I find this cleaner. Will refactor it to be shorter. Thanks to all :)

Comment: Keep in mind that if you have partial translation those solution will fail. You you plan to refactor code try to build one query solution.

Answer (score 2):

```
public function scopeLanguage($query, $language)
{
    $countQuery = clone $query;
    $countQuery->where('language', '=', $language);

    if ($countQuery->count() > 0) {
        return $query->where('language', '=', $language);
    } else {
        return $query->where('language', '=', "EN");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**MySQL specific** solution:

```
public function scopeLanguage($query, $language)
{
    $languages = [$language, 'EN'];

    $query->whereIn('language', $languages);

    $query->orderByRaw('field(language, ?, ?)', $languages);
}
```

then call `first` instead of `get`:

```
$query->language('DE')-> .... ->first();
```